# ggplotly in R studio fail to show results in viewer

Tags: ggplotly

I am trying to use the ggplotly to convert ggplot object and it returns nothing, just a blank viewer... Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

```
ggp = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_density(kernel = "gaussian")
ggplotly(ggp)
```

Comment: There are some posts with a similiar issue where updating RStudio fixed the issue. See e.g. https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-cant-plot-anything-using-plotly/55264/5 or https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1712

Comment: Sorry, but those posts do not solve my problem... i have the latest r studio and r and I can not use plotly at all. all my plots gave me a blank viewer...